# How to avoid a loop in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce, gitlab-ee

I am trying to update the tag of a version.json file in a repo and commit the same file to the repository through GitLab CI. This results in pipeline falling into a loop.

```
only:
  refs:
    - master
except:
  changes:
      - version.json
```

If I place the above block in the CI logic, the Pipeline does not pick this stage and if I remove the except block the Pipeline goes on incrementing the tag in version.json.

I am stuck with this since couple of days and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add in your commit message the tag `[CI SKIP] - commit message`

Gitlab will commit your changes without running a new pipeline